# email notification for sent or not

Tags: android

i tried this following code for knowing the resultCode

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if(requestCode==1 && resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK)    
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Mail sent.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if (requestCode==1 && resultCode==Activity.RESULT_CANCELED)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Mail canceled.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

but every time i got "Mail Canceled" message. 
can you please sort it out?
is there any particular code for knowing that default email client(i used gmail) sent the mail or not?
and

Answer (score 0):

> can you please sort it out?

The activity you are starting does not support `startActivityForResult()`.

> is there any particular code for knowing that default email client(i used gmail) sent the mail or not?

You have no way to find out if the user sent any email.